# Questions in number theory related to $NC$ and $P$-completeness

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory, integer-programming

1. Given $a,b\in\mathbb N$ find $\operatorname{GCD}(a,b)$.
2. Given $a,b,c\in\mathbb N$ find $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $ax+by=c$.

Euclidean algorithm solves both.

> My question is if either 1 or 2 is in functional $NC$ does it follow the other is in functional $NC$?

> Is there a variant of $1$ or $2$ which is $P$-complete? Ideally I would like the involved Diophantine equations to be of constant number of variables and constant degree.